# can't find control in FormView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview, findcontrol

I need find this `<a>` tag resided in a `FormView` control, I need to remove this a tag depending on the condition but I can't find it using `FormView.FindControl` method

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDiscipline" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FormView ID="fvMediaIntro" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>           
                  <div class="clipControls">
                     <a runat="server" id="iNeedToFindThis" href="#">here</a>
                  </div>
           </ItemTemplate>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I tried `fvMediaIntro.FindControl()` and `fvMediaIntro.Row.FindControl()`, neither worked.
Any idea please??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FindControl` will work only after those controls are created i.e when data is bound to the `FormView`. So you need to use appropriate event on `FormView` such [ItemCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcreated.aspx) or `DataBound`. For example,

```
protected void fvMediaIntro_ItemCreated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var control = fvMediaIntro.Row.FindControl("iNeedToFindThis") as HtmlAnchor;
}
```

Assuming, you are binding in `page_load` or using mark-up, you can also use `prerender` event of parent page/control safely to do `FindControl`.

Comment: can i iterate through all rows in Formview  ?

Comment: @PankajGarg, I am not sure what u mean by *all rows*! FormView display only one data row at a time - that can be access via `Row` property. Other row objects may exists based on settings e.g. `HeaderRow`, `FooterRow`, `TopPagerRow` etc