# How can I get text of hyperlink in a FormView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I was used a FormView to show data in my page :

```
        <asp:FormView ID="PFull" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="post_con">
            <h4 class="post-headers"><asp:HyperLink ID="hprPTitle" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("PID","~/Paper.aspx?pid={0}")%>'><%#Eval("PTitle")%></asp:HyperLink></h4>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

Bind form view :

```
public void ShowFullPaper(int id)
{
    DataTable dt = paper.ShowFullPaper(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pid"]));
    PFull.DataSource = dt;
    PFull.DataBind();
}
```

Now, I want change title of page with text of that hyperlink with this :

```
protected void PFull_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Title = ((HyperLink)PFull.FindControl("hprPTitle")).Text;
}
```

But That is not work. help me please...
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105634/cant-find-control-in-formview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your aspx markup as below.

```
<asp:FormView ID="PFull" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="post_con">
            <h4 class="post-headers"><asp:HyperLink ID="hprPTitle" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("PID","~/Paper.aspx?pid={0}")%>' Text='<%#Eval("PTitle")%>'></asp:HyperLink></h4>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

And then in your ItemDataBound event you could find it like below.

```
protected void PFull_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Title = ((HyperLink)PFull.FindControl("hprPTitle")).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change design to--

```
<asp:FormView ID="PFull" runat="server" OnDataBound="PFull_DataBound" >
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="post_con">
        <h4 class="post-headers"><asp:HyperLink ID="hprPTitle" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Dosage","~/Paper.aspx?pid={0}")%>' Text='<%#Eval("PTitle")%>'></asp:HyperLink></h4>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```